# Ошибка ext-mysqli is missing in composer.json

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm, composer

При попытке обработать следующие команды:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
mysqli_query
mysqli_close
```

phpStorm высвечивает ошибку ext-mysqli is missing in composer.json. 
версия php - 7.2

что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `composer.json` секцию `required` надо его добавить просто, как пример:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "php" : "^5.5 || ^7.0",
        "ext-mysqli": "*"
    }
}
```